# Form data collection in react-native using email

Tags: android, ios, react-native, email

I'm trying to implement a form to collect some feedback from the users and then send them to an email address. All the existing solutions I found to email, open up the email clients on the phone (react-native-mail, react-native-email). But what I need is, without opening an email client, the app should do the emailing. And should be work in both android and ios.

Is there any library or any configuration I can use to do the task?

Comment: Use a transactional email service for programmatically send an email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending an email from your react native app directly, without any user interaction, is impossible. But there are at least two workarounds.

**Workaround 1:**  If your app has a server backend, you can send the needed data via REST to your backend. Then you can use your own server as email server to send an email.

**Workaround 2:** Use an email service, where you contact a thrid party api to send your email. There are many options here. A quick google search resulted in [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/).